# How to set containers in row like content in linear layout Android

Tags: flutter

### I am new to fultter,And i want to do something like this

### |Textview:         Editext          |

No the thing is that i use yo apply layout_weigth to both textview "0.3"
and editext it is "0.7" and due t that this also becomes responsive on all screen, I want to do the same thing on flutter, Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Look into the Expanded class. You might want to start with the video for it in the "Widget of the Week" series on Youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo

When using Expandeds, I tend to make sure that all my flex values add to 100, and then use them like percentages. So here you would use a flex: 70 and the other one would be flex: 30

Comment: I have watched the video and it is so useful Thanks 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do same thing in the flutter by using Expanded in Row.

```
         Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Text(
                  "Name",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 7,
                child: TextFormField(
                  initialValue: "Enter text",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```